Efficient stochastic numerical integration over many trajectories
I am implementing a numerical method for solving stochastic differential equations using the Euler-Maruyama method.
What I have works, but it is not efficient. The reason is that because of the stochastic nature of the problem, I have many trajectories. Right now, I am solving them one by one. I have the feeling I should be able to parallelize them, as they are independent.
The working code looks like this
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from numba import jit, njit
import os

def A(u):
    x=u[0]
    y=u[1]
    z=u[2]
    
    omega=1/2*np.sqrt((1+8*kappa*z*z))  
    
    
    A=np.array([[-2,omega,0],
                [-omega,0,0],
                [0,0,-kappa]])

    
    du=A.dot(u)
    return du


def B(u,w):
    x=u[0]
    y=u[1]
    z=u[2]
    
    g=np.sqrt(kappa*nth)

    B=np.array([[0],
                [1],
                [1]])*g
    
    return np.reshape(B*w,len(u0))


def SDE(A,B):
    u = np.zeros((len(u0),Nmax+1,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64)
    for m in range(Mmax):
        u[:,0,m]=u0
        for n in range(0,Nmax):
            u[:,n+1,m] = u[:,n,m]+dt*A(u[:,n,m])+B(u[:,n,m],w[n,m])*np.sqrt(dt)   
            
    return u


#Parameters
kappa=0.05
nth=1.
gamma=1

Mmax=100 #number of trajectories

Tmax=10. ##max value for time
dt=0.05
Nmax=int(Tmax/dt) ##number of steps

t_list=np.arange(0,Tmax+dt/2,dt)


w = np.random.randn(Nmax+1,Mmax)

u0 = np.array([1., 0., np.sqrt(nth)/2])

u_t=SDE(A,B)

u_mean=np.mean(u_t,axis=2)


This code is a simplification of my real code, where I have a much larger dimension of the system and many more trajectories.
Notice how this is not efficient, because as I increase Mmax, I have to loop over them.
Ideally, I would like my solver to look something like
def SDE(A,B):
    u = np.zeros((len(u0),Nmax+1,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64)
    u[:,0,:]=u0
    for n in range(0,Nmax):
       u[:,n+1,:] = u[:,n,:]+dt*A(u[:,n,:])+B(u[:,n,:],w[n,:])*np.sqrt(dt)   
            
    return u


i.e., to be able to neglect the loop over m and just do it in a parallel fashion. However, naively doing so does not work.
Another ideal way to make it more efficient would be to use Numba. However, after many tries, I have not been able to implement njit with the SDE solver I define.

"However, naively doing so does not work." What about it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

@jared Oh, you are right: I do get an error. When I try to use u[:,0,:]=u0 I get "could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (3,50)". Which makes sense, because the LHS doesn't really know how to accommodate u0. Then, I assume the other part of the code, the loop, will also give me similar errors because of the matrix products I define in A and B.

What if you did u[:,0,:] = u0[:,None]? That should broadcast.

@jared it worked, i didn't know you could do that. Now, however, the error propagates to the way I defined A and B. For example, my next error is now from: np.reshape(B*w,len(u0)); return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order); cannot reshape array of size 150 into shape (3,)

When vectorizing code you have to consider the dimensionality (shapes) of all the terms and make sure you deal with all of them. Are you asking us to go through and fix all the shape issues for you?

I recommend starting in a new file (where you will write the vectorized version) and running the code in a debugger to go line by line and check the shape of each term, figure out what shape it should be, and properly reshape or add dimensions (like I said with u0) until your code is consistent.

You use np.complex64 but this looks suspiciously wrong. Do you know that np.complex64 is actually simple-precision complex numbers and not double-precision ones? Is this intended? If yes (unusual for such a code), why don't you use simple-precisions everywhere?

@JérômeRichard I was not aware of this... I thought it was the complex equivalent to np.float64 in terms of precision. What should then be the correct data type for double-precision complex numbers?

np.complex128 is the right one for double-precision. I have to say the naming convention is not very intuitive...

Here are the performance issues I found in the provided code:

A.dot(u) is clearly overkill here since the A matrix is a 3x3 matrix with only 4 non-zeros values. It is better to compute the expression manually, especially with Numba.
creating many small arrays like 3x3 2D arrays or even 1D arrays with only 3 items is very expensive, even in Numba (because arrays are dynamically allocated and reference-counted). You should preallocate array or even just use 3 variables (far more efficient). As a result, in Numba, returning new arrays is often less efficient than writing in existing preallocated array passed in parameter (for the above reason).
allocations generally do not scale so you should always reduce the number of allocations before running a computation with multiple threads.
iterating on the last axis is generally faster (on contiguous arrays), because items of the last axis are contiguously stored in memory while this is not the case of the one of other axis. As a result, it should be faster to swap the first and last axis in the computation of u. Its shape would be (Mmax,Nmax+1,len(u0)). For more information, please read: AoS versus SoA.
You can pre-compute some constants, especially when values are multiplied to 0.

Besides, np.reshape(B*w,len(u0)) is confusing since B is of size 3 so u0 must be also of size 3 and the reshape seems useless. Note that np.complex64 is for simple-precision (as stated in the comments).
Here is the resulting Numba code:
import numba as nb  # new

@nb.njit('(complex128[:], complex128[::1])')
def A(u, res):
    x=u[0]
    y=u[1]
    z=u[2]

    omega = 0.5 * np.sqrt((1+8*kappa*z*z))  

    res[0] = -2 * x + omega * y
    res[1] = -omega * x
    res[2] = -kappa * z
    return res

@nb.njit('(complex128[:], float64, complex128[::1])')
def B(u, w, res):
    g = np.sqrt(kappa*nth)
    res[0] = 0
    res[1] = g * w
    res[2] = g * w
    return res

# No signature is provided so the first call will be much slower
# But providing a signature here is complicated since A and B are functions
@nb.njit
def SDE(A,B):
    u = np.zeros((len(u0),Nmax+1,Mmax), dtype=np.complex128)
    sqrt_dt = np.sqrt(dt)
    for m in range(Mmax):
        u[:,0,m] = u0
        tmp1 = np.empty(3, dtype=np.complex128)
        tmp2 = np.empty(3, dtype=np.complex128)
        for n in range(0,Nmax):
            A(u[:,n,m],tmp1)
            B(u[:,n,m],w[n,m],tmp2)
            for i in range(3):
                u[i,n+1,m] = u[i,n,m] + dt * tmp1[i] + tmp2[i] * sqrt_dt
    return u

This is about 500 times faster on my machine (with a i5-9600KF CPU).
I think there is no need to use multiple threads once the code is optimized since the computation is finally pretty fast. If this is not enough, you can add the flag parallel=True and replace for m in range(Mmax) with for m in nb.prange(Mmax). However, this will not scale well due to false sharing caused by the bad memory layout. As stated in the above list, you should swap the axis 1 and 3 so to fix this issue.
In the end, the final code should look like this once parallelized and with a better memory layout:
# A and B are the same as before

# No signature is provided so the first call will be much slower
# But providing a signature here is complicated since A and B are functions
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def SDE(A,B):
    u = np.zeros((Mmax,Nmax+1,len(u0)), dtype=np.complex128)
    sqrt_dt = np.sqrt(dt)
    for m in nb.prange(Mmax):
        u[m,0,:] = u0
        tmp1 = np.empty(3, dtype=np.complex128)
        tmp2 = np.empty(3, dtype=np.complex128)
        for n in range(0,Nmax):
            A(u[m,n,:],tmp1)
            B(u[m,n,:],w[m,n],tmp2)
            for i in range(3):
                u[m,n+1,i] = u[m,n,i] + dt * tmp1[i] + tmp2[i] * sqrt_dt
    return u


# [...] same code

w = np.random.randn(Nmax+1,Mmax).T.copy()
u0 = np.array([1., 0., np.sqrt(nth)/2])
u_t=SDE(A,B)
u_mean=np.mean(u_t,axis=0)

This code is about 2000 times faster.
Note w is a global variable so it is considered as a compile-time constant by Numba (ie. it should never change during the application life-time), you should pass it in parameter if it is not the case.
By the way, note that Julia might be a better language for such a computation since the standard implementation is a JIT-compiler and we can easily avoid the creation of new temporary arrays (though creating new array is still quite expensive even in Julia).

what is a great answer and I will go in detail to check everything. However, the starting point is somewhat problematic for me: The example I provided was a toy model for my real code, in which the A and B matrices are much larger (10x10) and (10x1), so writing it manually is not always the most efficient. What would I need to change from your answer to keep A and B as the matrices I defined?

If A is a 10x10 matrix in practice, then you should preallocate it once (the way I have done with tmp1 and tmp2) and then write a loop to do the matrix multiplication yourself (since I do not think np.dot would be efficient and Numba seems not to support np.dot on complex numbers so far). If your real-world matrix have like >60% zeros, it is still a good idea to do the operation manually though this is cumbersome assuming you really care about performance.

In B, you can just replace the manual computation with a loop. This will be fast as long as 1. u0.size is known at compile time and 2. there are no temporary array created. If (1) is not true, then it will be slower but certainly not far more. If (2) is not true, then the allocation overhead will certainly be huge. Note that such details matter a lot since the bottleneck may not be the same with u0.size==10.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried what you said about the A matrix and it works to some extent. By that, I mean that Numba doesn't allow me to 'call' the variables, i.e. z=u[2]. So I can create a matrix A and do the matrix multiplication using Numba as long as z=cte, but if z=u[2] I get some error which cannot be described. (Numba errors usually are quite obscure for me). Still, I will try what you suggested to do the matrix operation manually, as I do care about performance. Thank you!

Yes Numba errors are not very user-friendly. It is hard for me to understand what happen with the provided information. I advise you to check the type is the same between the constant and u[2]. You can manually cast values for example with z = np.complex128(value).

I just adapted the code for my real case, and I have an unexpected problem: the kernel dies in my jupyter notebook file. The size is not even that big: Nmax:200, Mmax=2 and len(u0)=10. I have before simulated much more larger systems with Numba and didn't encounter this problem.

This can happen in 2 cases: out-of-bound memory accesses and race conditions. The most common is the first one. You can add the flag boundscheck=True and disable parallelism with parallel=False. Numba will tell you if there is an invalid memory access (but at the expense of a slower execution). This is a common issue with lower-level codes.

Actually, I found out the problem was from w = np.random.randn(Nmax+1,Mmax).T.copy(). If I remove .copy(), the kernel doesn't die and I can really increase the dimension of the problem. Totally unexpected and I don't know why

It does not make sens to me unless you use w[n,m] instead of w[m,n] (which should be detected by Numba with boundscheck=True anyway). Also make sure the function is recompiled since it assume w does not change since it is a global. (It is certainly safer to passe it in parameter IMHO).

Just one last thing: I am a bit confused about the temporal arrays, tmp. In your code, you call this: A(u[:,n,m],tmp1) and B(u[:,n,m],w[n,m],tmp2) without assigning it to any variable. Then, you call u[i,n+1,m] = u[i,n,m] + dt * tmp1[i] + tmp2[i] * sqrt_dt. It is correct to say that the values of A(u[:,n,m],tmp1) have been stored to  tmp1[i] implicitly?

Yes, the function A and B store their items in the array provided in the last argument (tmp1 and tmp2 here). This avoid creating an expensive new temporary array. In Python, the arguments cannot be modified (so the array reference is immutable), but the items of the array passed in parameter can be (so array items are mutable -- and there is no implicit array copy). An equivalent example of function doing this in Numpy is: np.multiply(arr1, arr2, out=resArr) which store the result in resArr without creating a temporary array (the out= is optional).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
